# How are fast-math flags added int the LLVM C++ API during code generation?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I have a builder that builds an operaion:

```
return BuilderBinop.CreateFMul(L, R, "multmp");
```

This generates

```
%multmp23 = fmul float %d22, %e21
```

Now I want to add fast-math flags to this. Specifically, I want to add the `fast` flag. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FastMathFlags fmf;
fmf.setFast(true);
BuilderBinop.setFastMathFlags(fmf);
```

The FastMathFlags class has helper methods to set flags. Since the interest here is to set the `fast` flag to true, the `.setFast()` comes in handy.

To clear the flags, the `.clear()` can be used.